# Potential OptaPlanner/Drools Bug: Strange MultiAccumulate ClassCastException

Tags: java, drools, classcastexception, optaplanner

**Instructions to reproduce are below.**

### Versions and Use

I'm using Drools for my scoring in an OptaPlanner planning engine.

1. OptaPlanner v8.8.0.Final
2. Drools      v7.55.0.Final

### The Question/Issue

Does a rule with this format implicitly cast the `MyConstraintConfiguration`?

Does the following rule have an invalid `accumulate`?

```
rule "name"
    when
        $cc : MyConstraintConfiguration()
        accumulate(PlanningEntity($key : key, $value : $cc.getCachedValue($key));
                                  $sumKeys : sum($key),
                                  $sumValues : sum($value);
                                  checkSum($sumValues))
    then
        // scoreHolder.penalize(...)
end
```

I have a rule very similar to this in my actual implementation.  It works without the second `sum` function, but adding the second causes a ClassCastException to be thrown in the generated Drools Java on a call to  `org.drools.model.functions.Function2$Impl::apply`.

Can you not have more than one `sum`?  I suspect that that is not a limitation considering the [Drools v7.56.0 Doc, Fig. 85](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.56.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html)

I unfortunately have been unable to get the generated code to print out for further inspection.

### To Reproduce

On the 8.8.x branch/tag

1. Add the this chunk of code to `ConferenceConstraintConfiguration`

```java
    public static final String NOT_A_RULE = "NotARule";
    @ConstraintWeight(NOT_A_RULE)
    private HardMediumSoftScore notARule = HardMediumSoftScore.ofHard(100_000);
    
    private int value = 1;
    
    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
    
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    public Integer getStringLength(final String s) {
        return map.computeIfAbsent(s, String::length);
    }
    
    public HardMediumSoftScore getNotARule() {
        return this.notARule;
    }
    
    public void setNotARule(HardMediumSoftScore notARule) {
        this.notARule = notARule;
    }
```

2. Add this nonsense rule to `conferenceSchedulingConstraints.drl`

```
rule "NotARule"
    when
        $ccc : ConferenceConstraintConfiguration($value : value)
        accumulate(Talk($titleLength : $ccc.getStringLength(title));
                   $totalLength : sum($titleLength),
                   $totalLength2 : sum($titleLength);
                   $totalLength > 0)
    then
        scoreHolder.penalize(kcontext, $totalLength);
end
```

Run `ConferenceSchedulingApp::main` or any test in `ConferenceSchedulingScoreHardConstraintTest` (after removing the class-level `@Disabled`) and you should get the `ClassCastException`

If this is a bug, let me know and I can create an issue for it.

### Full Stack Trace:

```
16:03:56.339 [EventQueue-0] INFO  Opened: data\conferencescheduling\unsolved\18talks-6timeslots-5rooms.xlsx
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.optaplanner.examples.conferencescheduling.domain.ConferenceConstraintConfiguration cannot be cast to class org.optaplanner.examples.conferencescheduling.domain.Talk (org.optaplanner.examples.conferencescheduling.domain.ConferenceConstraintConfiguration and org.optaplanner.examples.conferencescheduling.domain.Talk are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.optaplanner.examples.conferencescheduling.solver.P66.LambdaExtractor66506A5C685462CF06C48BF086E06788.apply(LambdaExtractor66506A5C685462CF06C48BF086E06788.java:1)
    at org.drools.model.functions.Function2$Impl.apply(Function2.java:35)
    at org.drools.model.view.BindViewItem2.eval(BindViewItem2.java:89)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.BindingEvaluator.evaluate(BindingEvaluator.java:39)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.BindingEvaluator.evaluate(BindingEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.LambdaAccumulator$BindingAcc.getAccumulatedObject(LambdaAccumulator.java:142)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.LambdaAccumulator.accumulate(LambdaAccumulator.java:77)
    at org.drools.core.rule.MultiAccumulate.accumulate(MultiAccumulate.java:118)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakAccumulateNode.addMatch(PhreakAccumulateNode.java:736)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakAccumulateNode.doLeftInserts(PhreakAccumulateNode.java:181)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakAccumulateNode.doNode(PhreakAccumulateNode.java:89)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.switchOnDoBetaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:588)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalBetaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:555)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:382)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.innerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:342)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.outerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:178)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evaluateNetwork(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:136)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.reEvaluateNetwork(RuleExecutor.java:228)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:91)
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.AbstractRuleEvaluator.internalEvaluateAndFire(AbstractRuleEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.SequentialRuleEvaluator.evaluateAndFire(SequentialRuleEvaluator.java:43)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:869)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.internalFireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:816)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:808)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1345)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1336)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1320)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.drools.DroolsScoreDirector.calculateScore(DroolsScoreDirector.java:105)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.DefaultScoreManager.updateScore(DefaultScoreManager.java:46)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.business.SolutionBusiness.getScore(SolutionBusiness.java:235)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.swingui.SolverAndPersistenceFrame.resetScreen(SolverAndPersistenceFrame.java:719)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.swingui.SolverAndPersistenceFrame.setSolutionLoaded(SolverAndPersistenceFrame.java:686)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.swingui.SolverAndPersistenceFrame$QuickOpenAction.actionPerformed(SolverAndPersistenceFrame.java:247)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.swingui.SolverAndPersistenceFrame.lambda$0(SolverAndPersistenceFrame.java:202)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(JList.java:1804)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(JList.java:1818)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:219)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:186)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setValueIsAdjusting(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:723)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JList.setValueIsAdjusting(JList.java:2152)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicListUI.java:2958)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:298)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Can you see if you can reproduce with the latest version of OptaPlanner available? The Drools team has recently fixed some of these issues and I'd like to be certain this is still an issue before I report it to them.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický I can confirm that this also occurs using OptaPlanner v8.10.0.Final.  Steps to reproduce are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Drools' Executable Model not providing the correct error message as this part of the rule is incorrect:

```
$cc : MyConstraintConfiguration()
accumulate(PlanningEntity($key : key, 
                          $value : $cc.getCachedValue($key)
...
```

You can't use the `$cc` variable inside the `PlanningEntity` binding.

I've filed a [JIRA](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-6552) for it.

Comment: I see!  Thank you.